# IBM Watson TTS example return a blank audio file

Tags: text-to-speech, ibm-watson

I have some troubles with the Watson TTS example provided by IBM using cURL :

```
curl -X POST -u {USERNAME}:{PASSWORD} \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--header "Accept:  audio/wav" \
--data '{"text":"hello world"}' \
--output hello_world.wav \
"https://stream.watsonplatform.net/text-to-speech/api/v1/synthesize"
```

I am running this cURL command through GitBASH but the audio file output I'm getting is blank and does not contain any audio.

I've tried changing :

```
--data '{"text":"hello world"}' \
```

to :

```
--data "{\"text\":\"hello world\"}" \
```

But I get the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the {} around your username and password credentials, which by the way are now compromise.

You will should revoke these credentials and create a fresh set of credentials, which you should try endevour to keep secret and not post in public forums.

Comment: Yes I had already revoked my credentials to see where the problem came from, so no problem if they are displayed in clear here. Nevertheless I found where the problem came from, I solved it by adding a -k to the first line, so it was not because of the {}. Thanks anyway !